# BeautifulSoup, lmxl not downloading time text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to download data from a website, everything is working fine except for when it encounters dates, it will just return "". I've looked at the html downloaded into the program and it has nothing between the  tags which is why it's returning nothing. When you inspect the html online you can see it there clearly. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

stocks=["3PL"]

keys = list()
values = list()

for stock in stocks:
    source = requests.get(r"https://www.reuters.com/companies/" + stock + ".AX/key-metrics").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    for data in soup.find_all("tr", class_="data"):
        keys.append(data.th.text)
        if data.td.text != "--":
            values.append(data.td.text)
        else:
            values.append("nan")

print(keys[3])
print(values[3])                    #This should return the date
```

Comment: It seems the data you're looking for is just missing when you fetch the page with requests. You may want to try this with an actual browser and selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem your data is added with javascript.  This is something requests will not handle as it won't render the page like a normal browsers. Only fetch the raw data.

However, you can use the `selenium` package to do this successfully.  To instal this:

```
pip install selenium
```

You may need to setup some web drivers to use Firefox, or Chrome.  But in the case below I used the browser that worked out of the box, being Safari.

I have adjusted your code a little to use the selenium package, and put your data in a dict to keep a nicer consistency.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

stocks=["3PL"]

response_data = {}
driver = webdriver.Safari()

for stock in stocks:
    url = r"https://www.reuters.com/companies/" + stock + ".AX/key-metrics"
    driver.get(url)
    source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
    for data in soup.find_all("tr", class_="data"):
        if data.td.text != "--":
            response_data[data.th.text] = data.td.text
        else:
            response_data[data.th.text] = 'nan'

driver.close()
```

Now you can check if the data is correctly downloaded:

```
print(response_data['Pricing date'])
Sep-04
```